# Xamarin.Forms - Possible to write custom renderer using original element name?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

In Xamarin.Forms, typically I'd write a custom renderer for buttons using a class name like "ButtonExt". Is it possible to write a custom renderer using the original name of (I guess overriding) the element, like "Button"?

Basically, I want to be able to add horizontal padding to all the buttons in my app, but without having to rename all `Button`s to `ButtonExt` (there is no Padding property for Buttons in Xamarin.Forms). In other words I want to be able say `new Button { Padding = 20 }` and not have to say `new ButtonExt { Padding = 20 }` (project is C#, not XAML).

Normally, in the iOS project, I'd have:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ButtonExt), typeof(ButtonExtRenderer))]
namespace StoreFulfillment.iOS
{
    public class ButtonExtRenderer : ButtonRenderer
```

and in the shared project, I'd have:

```
using MySharedProject;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MySharedProject.Renderers
{
    public class ButtonExt : Button
    {
        ...
```

And then I'd say `new ButtonExt { Padding = 20 }`. But in order to be able to write `new Button { Padding = 20 }`, I can't write `public class Button : Button`...so how do I accomplish this?

Comment: @hvaughan3 - just expanded my question - can you address the update question?

Comment: Wondering if Extension Methods is the answer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 2):

Sure! Just register it to a normal `Button` type and make sure you call all the base methods of the ones you override so the original working also remains.

So your attribute to register the renderer would just look like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(YourButtonRenderer))]
```

Also, make sure you actually need a custom renderer. If you just want to have a simple styling issue, look at the Xamarin.Forms [styling possibilities](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/) and especially implicit styling.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - will try. And yes I know all about styling, and how Buttons do *not* have a padding property :)

Comment: But in the Xamarin shared project, how would I create the class that I want to add custom properties to (i.e. Padding)? Using ButtonExt, I declare the class like `public class ButtonExt : Button {...` -- I can't do `public class Button : Button`...?

Comment: @jbyrd You cannot add custom properties to a class that has already been created unless that class is a `partial` class, which `Button` is not. So that leaves you with the option of, like you said, create extension methods or creating [Attached Properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties/) which is what the `Grid.Row` property is (meaning the `Button` class does not actually have a `Button.Grid.Row` property, but it can still be used on it). I do not think I would use attached properties for what you are trying to do, but it is an option nonetheless.